# Seeding fails upon `enum`

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, ruby-on-rails-4, seeding

I have problems using `enum`. I looked at the [documentation](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html) but don't understand what I'm doing wrong (sorry, I'm a newbie). I my model file I have:

```
enum origin: [ :website, :stand, :other ]
```

In my seeds file I create a new record with one of the key-value pairs being `origin: "website"`:

```
content = Faker::Lorem.paragraphs(2)
author.articles.create!( title: "Title",
                         origin: "website",
                         content: content )
```

Upon seeding this generates the error:

```
ActiveRecord::SubclassNotFound: Invalid single-table inheritance type: website is not a subclass of Article
```

What could be the cause of this error?

**Update:** I'm reading the same issue here: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/14136. But I don't understand it. Could someone please explain?

Article.rb:

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :author
  has_many :links
  validates :author_id, presence: true
end
```

Comment: Have you changed the inheritance_column in your model to origin ?

Comment: No, I read about it on the github post mentioned, but I don't understand what that means.

Comment: Please check my updated answer

Comment: If that doesn't work, please include the Article.rb model in your question

Comment: I added Article.rb to the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
author.articles.create!( title: "Title",
                         origin: :website,
                         content: content )
```

source for enums: http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html

for an in-depth read about enums: https://hackhands.com/ruby-on-enums-queries-and-rails-4-1/

Comment: Thanks, do you mean I need `origin: 0` in my seeds file? If I do that I get the error upon seeding: `NoMethodError: undefined method 'safe_constantize' for 0:Fixnum`.

Comment: Thanks, I changed it to `origin: :website` in my seeds. But this produces the error: `NoMethodError: undefined method 'safe_constantize' for :website:Symbol`. The documentation you mentioned does seem to suggest you need `origin: 0,` but as mentioned that didn't work either.

Comment: Okay, I found it, the problem is one of the columns names.